# You can use charset = "ISO-8859-1" on Google AMP project

Tags: html

I will show my problema:

It's works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>mytitle</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.djflkjslkfjsdlkfjsldkjfklsd.com/" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style  amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
    <noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none} 

    </style>

    </noscript>

  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

I can validate it on `#development=1`

But, if I change `<meta charset="utf-8">` for `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">`

It's stop to work:

```
The attribute 'charset' may not appear in tag 'meta name= and content='.
The mandatory tag 'meta charset=utf-8' is missing or incorrect. (see https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html#required-markup)
```

Reading the documentation [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html#required-markup). I had doubts about the charset. The `utf-8` is the only one that actually works?

Comment: It says it's *required* right there in the doc you linked to, so what's the question?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use ISO-8859-1? What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The utf-8 is the only one that actually works?

Yes. AMP requires UTF-8.

There's no reason to use ISO-8859 for new development in this century.